# Content larger on server than localhost

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, heroku, localhost

Everything seems to be displaying larger online (heroku) than running on localhost. Text, buttons, images, everything. I am using chrome to access both versions. Any reason this may be?

Comment: Is one of them zoomed (in the browser)? Chrome seems to remember the zoom level on a per-server basis.

Comment: Hmm, no it's not that.

Comment: If no zoom, do you've a proxy, some rules for intranet/local network? Is your page valid with a proper doctype? What about other browsers (Firefox, IE in a certain version)? Do you use `box-sizing` (also with proper prefix)? What's the exact difference in width of each blocks; is this remotely tied to `padding` and/or `border`? And for blocks without padding and border? How do you size text? In each case what's the calculated `font-size` for p and h1 for example